# Javascript - Uncaught TypeError with 2D Array

Tags: javascript

I have a simple html page with embedded js functions like below

```html
<script>
function getSelectedPlaces(rowNum, arr) {
    var count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (arr[rowNum][i] == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        ++count;
    }
    return count;
}

function start() {
    var arr = [
               [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
               [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
               [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
               ];
    alert(getSelectedPlaces(0, arr));
}

</script>

<p style="color: green">
The content above was created with JavaScript.<br>
This content is created with <b>HTML</b>.<br>
You can edit JavaScript and HTML in the left part of the page
and click "<b>Run code</b>" to view results in the right part of the page.
</p>
<b>LESSON 4: CALL A JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION:</b>
<input type=button onClick="start()" value="Generate random number">
```

However, I am getting an error saying `"JavaScript error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined on line 5"`, where line 5 is `if (arr[rowNum][i] == 0) {`

Looking for some help as I am new to JS

Comment: That's because you're missing `,` between your array items.

Comment: You have missed the commas in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate your sub-arrays with commas:

```
var arr = [
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are missing comma in array creation.

```
    var arr = [
               [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
               [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
               [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
               ];
```

```js
function getSelectedPlaces(rowNum, arr) {
    var count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (arr[rowNum][i] == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        ++count;
    }
    return count;
}

function start() {
    var arr = [
               [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
               [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
               ];
    alert(getSelectedPlaces(0, arr));
}
start();
```